# Why is "no-object" class in DINO-DETR not trained?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, object-detection

I am trying to do my own implementation of DINO-DETR (https://github.com/IDEA-Research/DINO), but i am having trouble understanding how they imapleneted the "no-object" label. The original code seems to completely ignore the "no-object" label.

The way i understand it should work. We have N classes (for example 91 in the case of COCO) + 1 for the "no-object" label. By that logic the "src_logits" should have dimensions (B, Q, 92). But looking at the implementation on github their class embedding function has dimesnions (B, Q, 91).

```py
_class_embed = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_classes)
```

Looking at their config files "num_classes" is set to 91 as per COCO.
More than just this their loss function also does not make sense to me. If output is of dimensions (B, Q, 91) and "num_classes" is equal to 91 don't they just cut off the "no-object" class in their loss? (I marked the line in code below).

```py
def loss_labels(self, outputs, targets, indices, num_boxes, log=True):
        """Classification loss (Binary focal loss)
        targets dicts must contain the key "labels" containing a tensor of dim [nb_target_boxes]
        """
        assert 'pred_logits' in outputs
        src_logits = outputs['pred_logits']

        idx = self._get_src_permutation_idx(indices)
        target_classes_o = torch.cat([t["labels"][J] for t, (_, J) in zip(targets, indices)])
        target_classes = torch.full(src_logits.shape[:2], self.num_classes,
                                    dtype=torch.int64, device=src_logits.device)
        target_classes[idx] = target_classes_o

        target_classes_onehot = torch.zeros([src_logits.shape[0], src_logits.shape[1], src_logits.shape[2]+1],
                                            dtype=src_logits.dtype, layout=src_logits.layout, device=src_logits.device)
        target_classes_onehot.scatter_(2, target_classes.unsqueeze(-1), 1)

        target_classes_onehot = target_classes_onehot[:,:,:-1]  # <--------HERE-------
        loss_ce = sigmoid_focal_loss(src_logits, target_classes_onehot, num_boxes, alpha=self.focal_alpha, gamma=2) * src_logits.shape[1]
        losses = {'loss_ce': loss_ce}

        if log:
            # TODO this should probably be a separate loss, not hacked in this one here
            losses['class_error'] = 100 - accuracy(src_logits[idx], target_classes_o)[0]
        return losses
```

Is there maybe anyone familiar with DETR or DINO-DETR here that could explain to me what I am missing? I am really lost.